# Onedrive from Ubuntu creates renamed files

Tags: sync

Recently my dad installed Onedrive-d on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. It works great - when I start the command it downloads every new file that has been added.

Now the only problem I have is with some files, like pictures or `.tex` (LaTex) files that appear double in my onedrive except that the name of my laptop is now added to the file name.

Example:  I edit the file `apple.jpeg` on a windows PC then it will sometimes show up as `apple(spectre).jpeg`

This is pretty annoying as LaTex needs the correct file name to display those images in my PDF document.

Any suggestions on what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely 'as designed' behavior by Microsoft with OneDrive: [See here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odedit/onedrive-creates-duplicate-file-name-with-pc-name/18f1fd5c-b217-49ee-8552-fa118a25bf1e). In this case, the only thing you can do is ensure both computers have access to the internet, otherwise the only thing you can do is manually delete and rename the files.

You can always try Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Thx i will check if this is indeed causing the problem. I have noticed that when i start onedrive on my laptop it updates every 5 minutes instead of auto updating each time something changes. Then I get messages indicating duplicate files so... maybe this is indeed the cause.